# I need a batch file which can start print test page from default printer

Tags: batch-file, printing, default

I want to create a batch file that can perform a print test page on execute. Problem is that I can't use code which I already have for any printer as far as it is set as default.

I have the following code which can run print test page command, but it only works if you will type in it name of the default printer.

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /k /n"Adobe PDF"
```

I was wondering if there is some sort of solution to connect the following two codes with if-else statements.

This code can print a test page -

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /k /n"Adobe PDF"
```

This code can check default printer -

```
wmic printer get name,default
```

Is there a way to create a batch file that can set the default printer name as a variable and use this variable in the second code to execute a print test page on the default printer all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to do it with the following batch file:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%printer_name%"
start /min notepad /P "\\fs\FIle Share\SA Support\ZverTools\printtestpage.txt"
```